# Boolean problems modeling a balcony on the facade

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make the balconies of the house I'm modeling, but it's not working with Boolean. It seems it is cut (because I see it cut in wireframe), but in the material preview, it's just a kind of frame visible, not the empty space I want to make. My facade is made with an array of wood boards, like in the tutorial video from Blender Guru (Making an abandoned house in 60 seconds). I don't know if the problem is that the house is not a cube, but an array. Thank you for helping! (see the link to the Blender file)

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FPZdM84FL7azRnc6cwga4FPF_evi8Rs0/view)

[enter image description here]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just change from fast to exact in the boolean modifier. Then it works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris ! :-D

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thanks.